# Create an S3 FTP server with s3fs+vsftpd error 500

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp, s3fs, vsftpd

in my project i have  to run an Linux EC2 instance like an FTP server connected to my S3 bucket directly.
After installing s3fs+fuse, vsftpd and all dependencies, configuring the conf files correctly, i do this:

First i create my folder fo ftp home:

```
$ mkdir -p s3dir
```

then change permission

```
$ sudo chmod 777 s3dir
```

Create an user for manage ftp home access:

```
sudo adduser test3
```

Assign readwrite permission to folder

```
$ sudo chown tests3:tests3 s3dir
```

now if i check:

```
$ sudo ls -la s3dir
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 tests3   tests3   4096 Mar  2 13:11 .
drwx------ 10 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Mar  2 13:11 ..
```

all done
Now with s3fs connect my folder endpoint to my S3 bucket like this:

```
s3fs mytestbucket s3dir -o passwd_file=~/.passwd-s3fs
```

at this point if i create a file in s3dir folder i see this on my S3, correctly.
Now is time to connect user to folder for vsftpd:

```
$ sudo usermod -d /home/ec2-user/s3test tests3
$ sudo service vsftpd restart
$ setenforce 0
```

everything would seem to be ok but when i can try to connect to my ftp server using test3 user and password error 500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/ec2-user/s3test appears

someone know where is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try making the home directory a subdirectory that you create inside the mounted bucket.  Unless something has changed, the mode of the mount point directory in s3fs is always fixed at 000 because of a quirk of how it handles directory permissions.  Using chown/chmod against the mount point before mounting does not have the intended effect, and after mounting is not supported.  Check this?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).